# mysql - It is ok to have n amount of columns?

Tags: mysql

I know it's possible to have n amount of columns, but is it proper mysql "coding standard"?

Here is what I'm doing:

I am a table `student` which includes all the students info including testScores:

```
student
-------
studId
name
age
gender
testId
```

Instead of putting each individual test answer within the `student` table, I made a separate table called `testAnswers` that will hold each students test results:

```
testAnswers
-----------
testId
ques1
ques2
.
.
.
quesN
```

Each entry in the `testAnswers` table corresponds to a specific student in the table `student`.

Of course, there will be an admin that will be able to add questions and remove questions as each year the test questions may change. So, if the admin were to remove an answer, than that means one of the columns would be removed.

Just to reiterate myself, I know this is possible to edit and remove columns in a table in mysql, but is good "coding standard"?

Comment: You failed to satisfy the first normal form. Congratulations.

Comment: @JanDvorak Not if he uses the two tables he hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a simple and clear: *No*. That's just not how you should do it except for very few corner cases.

The usual way to approach this is to normalize your database. Normalization follows a standard procedure that (among other things) avoids having a table with columns names `ques1, ques2, ques3 ...`.

This process will lead you to a database with *three* tables:

`students`  - id, name, and other stuff that applies to one student each

`questions` - id and question text for each question

`answers`   - this is a N:M relation between students: student_id, question_id, answer_value

Answer (score 1):

**Use two tables!**

What you are describing is a `one to many` relationship as there can be `one` student to `many` test scores. You would need to have some `id` as a foreign key to the `student_id` and put this `id` in the `testAnswers` table. You can then set constraints, which tell the database how to handle removal of data.

As one commenter has mentioned, using one table would result in breaking `1nf` or `first normal form` which basically says that you cannot have multiple values for a single column given a particular record - You can't have multiple test scores for the same user in a given table, instead break the data up into two tables.

Comment: Sorry, this answer (even after its recent edit) is still misleading. It is a many-to-many relationship (not one-to-many), and it involves three tables. It also would need two foreign keys, not one.

Comment: @Hazzit I was only responding to the test answers and the student, in which case only two tables are needed and it would be a one to many :)

Comment: Correct in the way that every N:M relationship is modeled as two 1:n relationships. Your testAnswers table is missing a) a primary key or b) any other compound unique key which makes it unusable for any practical purposes.

Comment: @Hazzit You're correct in the sense that I didn't write out every single detail for the user. Some things can / should be learned. The answer I gave demonstrates the general layout the user should assume. Yes, primary keys are necessary but I figured that I was somewhat obvious

Answer (score 0):

...of course 2 tables, also could use 3, just remember to insert a studId column also in the testAnswers table (with REFERENCE to the student table) and an INNER JOIN testAnswers ON student.studId=testAnswers.studId at the SELECT query (to read the data).